# react js : the map function didn't work inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, react-hooks

i have a mini tp that i want to map a array of objects , and i find a problem of the function map didn't working , in this tp i have the function `App()` use the function `Ptot()` that map a array of objects with the function `Prot()`

**the problem:**
`

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function
    at Ptot (Ptot.js:9:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

`

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";

import Ptot from "./Ptot";
const Produits=[
    {
        id:1,
        title:"pc pourtable hp",
        prix:'7490',
        image:""
    },
    {
        id:2,
        title:"pc pourtable delet",
        prix:'8990',
        image:""
    },
    {
        id:1,
        title:"pc pourtable infnx",
        prix:'6590',
        image:""
    }
];
function App(){
    return(
        <div>
          hello

          <Ptot props={Produits} />
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

**Prot.js:**

```
import React from "react";
function Prot(element) {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>hello</p>

            <div>
                <div className="col">
                    <div className="cart-shadow-sm">
                        <img className="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" src={`image/${element.image}`} alt="" />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <p className="card-title">{element.title}</p>
                            <p className="card-text">{element.prix}</p>
                            <div className="d-flex justify-conten-between align-items-center">
                                <div className="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Ajoute un paner</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Prot;
```

**Ptot.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Prot from './Prot.js'
import { useState } from "react";
function Ptot(props){
    const [data,setData]=useState(props)
    return (
        <div className="container">
            
            <div >
                {
                    data.map((elm)=>{
                        <Prot element={elm} />
                    })
               
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    
}
export default Ptot;
```

Comment: If you write [].map((elm)=>... it will not throw error. That means the error comes because of the incorrect property input flow into the components. Please write console.log(data) and paste result here

Answer (score 0):

A component's `props` is an object. Don't call a `props` property `props`, call it something else like `data`:

```
<Ptot data={Produits} />
```

and then destructure `data` from the component props object, and `map` over that instead.

```
function Ptot({ data }) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you render a React component, all the props get passed into the component function as a single argument (most often called `props`).

So when you have this

```js
<Ptot props={Produits} />
```

Inside your `Ptot` function, it’s actually passed in like this

```js
function Ptot (props) {
  console.log(props);
  // { props: […] }
  console.log(props.props);
  // [{ id: 1, …}, …]
}
```

So what you want is something like this instead

```js
<Ptot data={Produits} />
```

```js
function Ptot(props) {
  return props.data.map(elm => (…));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the props in `Ptot.js` as object field

```
.
.

function Ptot({props}){
.
.
```